# Same absolute path on linux and windows 7

Tags: windows, linux, firefox-extensions, path, firefox-profile

I have windows 7 and ubuntu on dual-boot and I'm sharing the same firefox profile folder on both OSs, which is located on the windows partition (which is mounted on ubuntu startup automaticaly).
My problem is that I'm using the FEBE extension (which creates backups of my profile for recovery purposes) but it needs me to set a folder absolute path to tell it where the backup should be created so that, on windows, it doesn't allow a path without a letter and backslashes like "c:\whatever". But when I open firefox on linux, this path has no meaning and backups are not done.
Is there a way to have one absolute path that's understandable by both OSs? Even if it doesn't point to the same place on each OS?

Note: I found two similar questions on this forum (though realating to different contexts) but none of the suggested answers work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FEBE also offers integrated cloud storage (thru Box.net) so you can access the backup that way from both the Ubuntu and Windows partitions.  Since you are sharing the exact same Fx profile, it doesn't matter which platform does the actual backup and posting to Box.net.  It's the very same data getting backed up, so you should only have one platform or the other perform the backup (not both).

Comment: you're right. I just wished to be able so make backups on both OSs cause I have lots of extensions and my profile is very big, so uploading it to box.com takes too much time. Besides, I often change it on both OSs so I'm always afraid something goes wrong when I open firefox on the other OS. That's why I wanted to create backups on both. Nonetheless, I just discovered FEBE is not working on my ubuntu and I don't know why. Even setting to path to a usual linux folder, it begins to create a backup but soon freezes and never finishes so that I have to close firefox!

Answer (score 2):

No, you cant. The two different OS reference drives and partitions in different manners.

Windows has each partition as a letter. Linux will have a single partition mounted as / and then attach other drives to mount points therein.

The closest you could do, is to have an alias somewhere in your backup system which will replace the c:\ with the path to your windows partitions linux mount point, or vice versa.

Comment: Aren't aliases only for commands? Can I create an alias to a path on Ubuntu?