# Windows Browser to Open Files Having Linux Path Names

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows, firefox, bookmarks

I have several Linux machines and one Windows 7 machine.  I sync my Firefox bookmarks between all machines by syncing the "places.sqlite" file among all platforms.

On the Linux machines, I have a folder

```
/home/user/favs
```

that contains various files that I like to open using my browser.  The Windows machine contains said files in its

```
C:\Users\user\My Documents\synced\favs
```

folder.

Almost all of my work is done on the Linux machines, so naturally the file locations in the bookmarks of said browser-referenced files all reflect their Linux pathnames.

I cannot open these files via Firefox on the Windows machine, as the [file URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme%20%22file%20URI)'s of the files are different across the Windows and Linux platforms.

For example, the location (for the browser's purposes) of a particular file I want to open with the browser (by clicking on its bookmark) is

```
file:///home/user/favs/foo.txt
```

while in Windows, the equivalent file URI would, of course, be

```
file:///C:/Users/user/My Documents/synced/favs/foo.txt
```

**What can I do to the above Windows** `favs` **folder so that my browser will open that file, keeping in mind that the subject bookmark is indicating said target file's *Linux* file URI?**

I've fiddled around with the Windows `subst` and `join` commands, as well as [mount point folder paths](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/subst.mspx?mfr=true).  I've also looked at [drive mapping](https://superuser.com/questions/300098/how-do-i-map-a-local-path-to-a-drive-letter-in-windows-7) and [absolute path guidance](https://superuser.com/questions/508033/same-absolute-path-on-linux-and-windows-7) without success.

Ever since adopting Linux several years ago, my Windows knowledge has flagged badly (the Windows 7 machine is my wife's).

Comment: Do have a reason for not using Firefox's built in syncing feature? It's cross-platform.

Comment: Well, I've got all of my syncing operations automated (using Unison), and I'd like to avoid adding additional steps to the process.  Also, I'm not sure that it Firefox's built-in syncing feature will work for the case of local data files being referenced in the bookmarks, which is the case being considered here.